# How does JS know about its inbuilt functions and custom written function?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

For an eg if we consider console.log() function, we don't need to define it anywhere and straight away we can use it.

Is there any way where I can define my custom function, say console.logV2() which I can use across all the files without explicitly importing the function like console.log()?

And, How does JS know which are the inbuilt functions present in it? Is it being done by some interpreter?

Comment: "*How does JS know which are the inbuilt functions present in it?*" they are part of the specifications. So, if you have a JS environment, it has to provide a `parseInt` function, for example. Otherwise it's not a spec compliant JS environment. And might not even be fit to be called JS. Different environments have more specs, like the browser providing `document` or Node.js providing `queueMicrotask`.

Comment: Built in functions are built in. It's literally in the name.

Answer (score 1):

There is standard objects and function in js, you can list all of them just type `window` in console.

This is build in browser function

[ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/about-ecma/members/) create standards, then developers create js engines like [javascript v8](https://v8.dev/docs) (google), Nitro (Safari), then this js engines implementation in browsers

All methods is part of window, for example `console.log('hello')` is same like `window.console.log('hello')`.

When you create function like:

```
function someFunction(){
  return 5;
}
```

you can call it like `window.someFunction()` or `someFunction()`.

**So you can't create function like console.log** (for call in all pages and sites) but you can create function for one project/page

For one project/page you can add your own methods for build in functions like:

```
console.log2 = function(){return 5}
```

After that you can call this method in any part of page:

```
console.log("hello") // return hello
console.log2() // return 5
```

But its working like regular js (first you need create this function and then call it)